# Remove word from a string

Tags: php, string-matching

I have a csv file that contains company names. I would want to match it against my database. In order to have a cleaner and nearer matches, I am thinking of eliminating some company suffixes like 'inc', ' inc', ', inc.' or ', inc'. Here's my sample code:

```
$string = 'Inc Incorporated inc.';
$wordlist = array("Inc","inc."," Inc.",", Inc.",", Inc"," Inc");

foreach ($wordlist as &$word) {
    $word = '/\b' . preg_quote($word, '/') . '\b/';
}

$string = preg_replace($wordlist, '', $string);
$foo = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $string);
echo $foo;
```

My problem here is that the 'inc.' doesn't get removed. I'm guessing it has something to do with the preq_quote. But I just can't figure out how to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It may involve type juggling at some point, but will have your desired result

```
    $string = 'Inc Incorporated inc.';
    $wordlist = array('Inc', 'inc.');

    $string_array = explode(' ', $string);

    foreach($string_array as $k => $a) {
        foreach($wordlist as $b) {
            if($b == $a){
                unset($string_array[$k]);
            }
    }

    $string_array = implode('', $string_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$string = 'Inc incorporated inc.';
$wordlist = array("Inc","inc.");

foreach ($wordlist as $word) {
    $string =str_replace($word, '', $string);
}
echo $string;
```

OR

```
$string = 'Inc Incorporated inc.';
$wordlist = array("Inc","inc.");
$string = str_replace($wordlist, '', $string);
echo $string;
```

This will output as 'corporated'...

If you want "Incorporated" as result, make the "I" is small.. and than run my above code (first one)...

Comment: That would echo `orporated`

Comment: If you want "incorporated" as result, make the "I" small.. and than run my above code (first one)...

Answer (score 0):

[image]You can use this

```
$string = 'Inc Incorporated inc.';
$wordlist = array("Inc "," inc.");
$foo = str_replace($wordlist, '', $string);
echo $foo;
```

Run this code [here](http://writecodeonline.com/php/)

Comment: Hi @Tushar Gupta, it outputs 'orporated'. It should get the whole Incorporated.

Comment: I should tell you that the $wordlist is composed of many suffixes. One of them is ' Inc'. So it will still return 'orporated'.

Comment: @user3360031 please see i have placed the screen shot of the code output

Answer (score 0):

This will work for any number of elements in array...

```
$string = 'Inc Incorporated inc.';
$wordlist = array("Inc");

foreach($wordlist as $stripped)
$string = preg_replace("/\b". preg_quote($stripped,'/') ."(\.|\b)/i", " ", $string) ;

$foo = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $string);
echo $foo;
```